# Manipulating the order of items in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am a not an experienced programmer so please bear with me.I have been trying to solve this problem for hours to no avail. I would really appreciate a solution to my problem.

Create a program that will:

- reverse the order of a list if the list consists of integers alone
- Will convert the list items to uppercase if the list contains words 
  only.
- Will return the same list if the list members don’t satisfy either of
  these two criteria

**Edit: This question is a duplicate**

Here is my test code:

```
import unittest
import switchreverse
class Reverser(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Reverse(self):
        word_lists = [1,2,3,4,5]
        for e in word_lists:
            if type(0):
                assert word_lists.reverse()
            if type(''):
                assert word_lists.upper()
            else:
                return word_lists
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the code being tested:

```
def Switchreverser():
    word_lists = [1,2,3,4,5]
    for e in word_lists:
        if type(0):
            word_lists.reverse()
        elif type(''):
            word_lists.upper()
        else:
            return word_lists
```

Here is the error I am recieving:

```
 F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_Reverse (__main__.Reverser)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_switchreverse.py", line 8, in test_Reverse
    assert word_lists.reverse()
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.reverse` modifies `list` in-place and returns `None`, so `assert list.reverse()` is the same as `assert None` which obviously raises `AssertionError`.

Unrelated, but `if type(0)` and `if type('')` are **not** going to check the type of the lists' elements. Instead, you should be doing `if all(isinstance(element, int) for element in list)`.